# Are there any databases support mutual recursion query

Tags: sql, database

I have tried sql server,db2,postgreSQL and Mysql.Some support the basic function of recursion,none of them support mutual recursion like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
x (id) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT id+1 FROM y WHERE id < 5),
y (id) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT id+1 FROM x WHERE id < 5)
SELECT * FROM x;
```

Answer (score 0):

it is possible: just use the `second cte`(`y (id)`) as a **subquery**

```
WITH 
x (id) AS (SELECT 1 
           UNION ALL 
           SELECT y.id+1 FROM 
           (SELECT 1 id UNION ALL SELECT id+1 FROM x WHERE id < 5) y
           WHERE y.id < 5)
SELECT * FROM x;
```

This method works for most of RDBMSs you mentioned .
but such these queries may put inside an **infinite loop**.